# Semicolon issue in SQL script

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I need to update a column value with a stored procedure which contains a semicolon, and this is causing an issue "quoted string not properly ended".

Connected to server using Putty and executing command using SQL Plus

Tried to use /; but it didn't work

```
update dummy_table
  set
  col1 = 0, col2 = null, col3 = to_clob(
    'declare
    source_table varchar2(40) := :par1;
    target_table_name varchar2(40) := :par2;
    '||'
    begin  '||'
    select * from temp_table;
    end;
    '||'/'
  ), col4 = null
  where col5 = 'value_1' and col6 = 'value_7';
```

ER: Command should get execute successfully and it should update col3 with given value

AR: Quoted String not properly ended

Comment: @ADyson I got the impression that OP was attempting to concatenate using double bar operator to insure a line feed was present in their `col3` SQL string that is being generated here. I feel like this may be better accomplished using `SET SQLBLANKLINES ON` but I'm not expert here.

Comment: it's not an "escaping issue". yes, the first single quote in `'||'` ends the string literal, but that string literal is followed by the `||` concatenation operator, which is then followed by a single quote that starts another string literal. Behavior observed by OP is not a SQL issue per se, it's sqlplus prematurely identifying the end of the statement when it encounters a semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

The semi-colon tells SQLPlus you want to run what you have typed in so far as a command.  It does not look first to see you are in the middle of a quoted string.
To stop this action, enclose you entire command in its own block, where the semi-colon will be considered part of the block and not try to execute what you have entered so far. Blocks are surrounded by the BEGIN and END keywords.  Tell SQLPlus you are done by entering a period on its own line, then run the block by entering a slash.

So, if you were typing into SQL*Plus, it would look like this:

```
BEGIN
update dummy_table
  set
  col1 = 0, col2 = null, col3 = to_clob(
    'declare
    source_table varchar2(40) := :par1;
    target_table_name varchar2(40) := :par2;
    '||'
    begin  '||'
    select * from temp_table;
    end;
    '||'/'
  ), col4 = null
  where col5 = 'value_1' and col6 = 'value_7';
END;
.
/
```

Comment: Since when does SQLPlus use the `.` on a single line?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Beats me.  See the "Running PL/SQL Blocks" section on this page: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_four.htm#i1039663

Answer (score 0):

You can use the alternative quoting mechanism technique of Oracle as mentioned in the following solution:

```
UPDATE DUMMY_TABLE
SET
    COL1 = 0,
    COL2 = NULL,
    COL3 = TO_CLOB('declare
    source_table varchar2(40) := :par1;
    target_table_name varchar2(40) := :par2;
    '
    || '
    begin  '
    || '
    select * from temp_table;
    end;
    '
    || q'#/#'),
    COL4 = NULL
WHERE
    COL5 = 'value_1'
    AND COL6 = 'value_7';
```

String, which contains any special oracle reserved characters and If you want to consider it as a string then you need to use quoted string: `q'<Special symbol><Your string><Special symbol>'`.

Please refer to the [Alternative Quoting Mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-1824CBAA-6E16-4921-B2A6-112FB02248DA) technique of Oracle in the Oracle documentation.

Answer (score 0):

SQLPlus doesn't seem to like the semicolons at the end of the line, whether they are part of a quoted string or not. This works, and it is the same as your statement but with line breaks (CR+LF) added:

```
update dummy_table
    set
    col1 = 0, col2 = null, col3 = to_clob(
      'declare
      source_table varchar2(40) := :par1;' || chr(10) || chr(13) ||'
      target_table_name varchar2(40) := :par2;' || chr(10) || chr(13) ||'
      '||'
      begin  '||'
      select * from temp_table;' || chr(10) || chr(13) ||'
      end;' || chr(10) || chr(13) ||'
      '||'/'
    ), col4 = null
    where col5 = 'value_1' and col6 = 'value_7';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set sqlterminator off
update dummy_table
  set
  col1 = 0, col2 = null, col3 = to_clob(
    'declare
    source_table varchar2(40) := :par1;
    target_table_name varchar2(40) := :par2;
    '||'
    begin  '||'
    select * from temp_table;
    end;
    '||'/'
  ), col4 = null
  where col5 = 'value_1' and col6 = 'value_7'
/
set sqlterminator on
```

Comment: You should edit your question in order to explain what you do, and how it solve the issue.

Comment: Why was this downvoted. It appears to solve the op's issue (and mine)